# Angle of rotation based on apparent change in size

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a camera set up which views an object in 2D in front of it square on that's 309mm away, the object changes in size by 0.073mm. What I am trying to calculate is by what angle has the object to rotate through on its vertical axis to create this apparent change in size.

A good way to visualise my problem is a dinner plate held vertically which is rotated clockwise about this vertical axis. In reality it has the same width but looking at it, it seems to be thinner.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I guess that the apparent diameter of a disk should simply vary with $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: The change in size is not enough to determine the angle, since the outcome depends on the initial position of the object.

Comment: I am taking the assumption that it starts flat on to the camera

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the disk - or plate - has a diameter $D_1$ when viewed from the front, and that after the rotation by an angle $\theta$ it has an apparent diameter of $D_2$. Then the two quantities are related by
\begin{equation}
D_2=D_1\cos\theta
\end{equation}
assuming that $\theta$ is the angle formed by the plane of the disk and the plane of view.
Since you have the variation, i.e. $\Delta D=D_2-D_1$, you might rewrite that equation like this:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta D}{D_1}=\cos\theta-1
\end{equation}
which yields
\begin{equation}
\theta=\arccos \left(1+\frac{\Delta D}{D_1}\right)
\end{equation}
Note that you cannot determine the angle if you don't know the actual diameter of the object.